# how to upgrade primefaces version in eclipse by using maven?

Tags: eclipse, jsf, maven, primefaces

I want to upgrade my primefaces version from 3.1.1 to 4.0.4
I have tried writing 4.0.4 to pom.xml but it shows errors like Missing artifact org.primefaces:primefaces:jar:4

How can i do it?
                    
            org.primefaces
            primefaces
            3.1.1

Comment: Primefaces 4.0.4 is a Elite release. It's only available to ELITE and PRO users, you won't see it in Maven repos. http://primefaces.org/downloads.html

Comment: I tried other versions which are  for community. but it shows error again.

Comment: error is "Missing artifact org.primefaces:primefaces:jar:4"

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, 4.0.4 version is only for elite registered users, but you might try to edit the pom.xml and write 4.0 instead of 4.0.4, wich is intended to general public.

Comment: thanks I did it but it is not enough also, I imported 4.0 jar to library.